# ASP.NET Dynamic Data - Custom Pages for derived types

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data, derived-types, custom-pages

I am able to create custom pages for a base type, but not for any of its derived types.

I have a Product class and derived types LightPipe and CardGuide. I created a custom page under CustomPages/Products/List.aspx. This work fine; Dynamic Data uses the custom page when displaying base Product entities.

However, when I create a custom page for LightPipe under CustomPages/LightPipes/List.aspx, Dynamic Data still uses the standard page template under PageTemplages/List.aspx rather than my custom template.

Is this a limitation of Dynamic Data?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Added clarification.

Comment: What do you mean by base type or derived types in terms of custom pages? Do you mean to say you are creating a custom class and want to create its page template?

Comment: Hi Kundan, thanks for the comment. I have added clarification to my question which addresses your comment.

Comment: Are LightPipe class created in database already or you have created these custom classes?

Comment: LightPipe and all other entities have been created on the database already. It is a database-first approach, and everything works correctly except the custom pages for subtypes of Product such as LightPipe, CardGuide, LED.

Comment: What URL is showing when you navigate to LightPipe aspx page?

Comment: The URL is http://localhost/LightPipe/List.aspx

Comment: its mean than you should create the directory in CustomPages with the name of **LightPipe** instead of **LightPipes**.